# Call function on html page from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Long story short:

I have the following file structure:

```
class RandomCtrl {
    constructor(randomService) {
    this.randomService = randomService;
    ...
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);
    }

    ...

    }

    updateLegendChart(){
         RandomCtrl.chartStuff.chart.unload("ID-1234");
    }

    function getData(RandomCtrl) {

        RandomCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(DemandCtrl.dataParams).then(result => {
        RandomCtrl.result = result.data;
        RandomCtrl.siteNames = result.data.map(element => element.SiteName);
        RandomCtrl.keys = Object.keys(result.data);
        RandomCtrl.chartStuff = getChart(result.data);  
        RandomCtrl.chartStuff.chart.unload("ID-1234");   ////<-HERE IT WORKS!!!

    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
    }


    function getChart(data) {
        const chartOptions = getWeekHourlyOptions(data);

        const allCols = [].concat(chartOptions.dataColumns);

        ...
        return {allCols, chart};
    }

    ...

    RandomCtrl.$inject = ['randomService'];

    export const Random = {
        bindings: {
            data: '<',
            siteNames: '<'
        },
        templateUrl: randomPageHtml,
        controller: RandomCtrl
    };
```

I have a chart containing multiple lines each of them representing a site, I want to remove or add them when I click on their name in a legend section.

I do this by using `load` and `unload` methods of [Billboard.js](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Chart.html#load).

If a write it inside `getData()`, the line with **HERE IT WORKS**, it works but it does it every time I run the code, I want to do it only when I click a button.

The problem is that I cannot glue this functionality to an `ng-click` into an html page.

This is the html page:

```
<div class="demand page">
    <div  class="chart-legend-container">
        <div ng-repeat="site in $ctrl.keys">
            <chart-legend site="$ctrl.siteNames[site]" keys= "$ctrl.keys"></chart-legend>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.updateLegendChart()">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

My approach was to use `updateLegendChart()` which is a method on the controller  which should be called when `ng-click` is triggered.

The method is in the controller and looks like this:

```
updateLegendChart(){
    RandomCtrl.chartStuff.chart.unload("ID-1234");
}
```

The error says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined

Any idea how to call that function properly?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `$onInit` hook 'this' keyword refers to the `$onInit` context , not to `RandomCtrl`

```
$onInit() {
    getData.call(null, this);
}
```

Probably something you don't want to do, because then you're appending all those properties (result, chartStuff, etc.) to the wrong object.

```
..
//here RandomCtrl is still $onInit context, and not the the class context
RandomCtrl.chartStuff = getChart(result.data);
```

As a consequence when you invoke `updateLegendChart()`, RandomCtrl doesn't have any chartStuff field, thus you get the exception "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined"

```
updateLegendChart(){
   RandomCtrl.chartStuff.chart.unload("ID-1234");
}
```

if you try passing RandomCtrl directly you should be fine.

```
$onInit() {
    getData.call(null, RandomCtrl);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with that part. `RandomCtrl.chartStuff.chart.unload("ID-1234");` works fine inside `getData`, I want to make it work inside the html page, something like this: `$ctrl.updateLegendChart()`

Comment: It works because inside getdata() you're referring to the same object (RandomCtrl) whether when you call the unload from within updateLegendChart() you refer to a different  RandomCtrl.

Comment: Tried your approach, changed from `this` to `RandomCtrl` inside `$onInit()` but now it throws this error: `Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined` . Probably it doesn't like it like that

Comment: when I use this, it looks as this:`RandomService:RandomService {authService: {…}, $http: ƒ}
data:undefined
dataParams:{date: {…}, granularity: "FIFTEEN_MINUTES"}
siteNames:undefined
__proto__:Object`

Comment: when I replace this with RandomCtrl: `ƒ RandomCtrl(RandomService)`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work as expected it should be replaced `RandomCtrl` with `this` inside `updateLegendChart()` method like this:

```
updateLegendChart(siteNames){

    this.chartStuff.chart.unload(siteNames);
}
```

It doesn't need to modify `$onInit()` method, it should be let as it is